# Is my FRX780M motherboard compatible with AMD FX -8350 cpu??

Tags: cpu, motherboard, gpu

Is my Acer FRX780M motherboard compatible with AMD FX -8350 cpu??
Do i need to upgrade my motherboard BIOS also?
And if someone wants they could tell the process of changing to new processor..

Comment: Please provide an english product website for the Acer FRX780M. **What CPU do you currently have?** Update your question with this information and I will remove the downvote.  I would contact Acer directly for a complete AM3+ CPU compatability list.